# JPanel font doesn't match with printing output

Tags: java, swing, printing, fonts

I wanna print my jpanel through thermal printer. But when I print the panel, output's font doesn't match with panel font. Panel has JLabels and images . I've sent the code below. If you can help, I will really appreciate !

```
public static class Printer implements Printable {
    final Component comp;

    public Printer(Component comp) {
        this.comp = comp;
    }

    @Override
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index)
            throws PrinterException {
        if (page_index > 0) {
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }

        // get the bounds of the component
        Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

        // get the bounds of the printable area
        double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();

        double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
        double pYStart = format.getImageableY();

        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


        g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
        g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
        comp.paint(g2);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the desired font to all the child components. Set the font to all the labels because they don't use parent's font.

Comment: How can I do this ? So my labels in panel already have fonts .

Comment: They have some font set from L&F but they doesn't use parent panel's font

Comment: How can I change all child components' fonts ?

Comment: Do you have any idea ? My each label has own font. If I set all child fonts  in jpanel , all labels will have same fonts .

Comment: Use getComponentCount/getComponent

Comment: public static void changeFont(Component component, Font font) {
  component.setFont(font);
  if (component instanceof Container) {
   for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
    changeFont(child, font);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: this method changes all labels font , all labels will have same fonts. Each label should has own font.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. What's the JPanel's font? How do you see the "doesn't match"?

Comment: My panel has labels. Each label has own font different sizes, different styles. But if I call changeFont that I've sent above, it make all child comps as panel font . I do not want this happen. Do you understand the problem ?